# How to write a query for "Select the site_id and location of sites in Europe where the students are not living in the UK"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two separate queries:

```
SELECT SITE_ID, LOCATION
FROM SITES
WHERE LOCATION LIKE 'Europe%';
```

and

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_FNAME, STUDENT_LNAME, COUNTRY
FROM STUDENTS
WHERE COUNTRY NOT LIKE 'UK';
```

How to write a query which would select the `site_id` and `location` of sites in `Europe` where the students are not living in the `UK`?

A query that takes one from the other and applies to the following structure:

```
SELECT column_name1
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
OPERATOR
SELECT column_name1
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
```

I have added `UNION ALL` operator (I have no idea if I'm using it correctly), but the result is:

```
SELECT SITE_ID, LOCATION
*
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>       ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns
>   .

```
SELECT SITE_ID, LOCATION
FROM SITES
WHERE LOCATION LIKE 'Europe%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_FNAME, STUDENT_LNAME, COUNTRY
FROM STUDENTS
WHERE COUNTRY NOT LIKE 'UK';
```

Comment: Is there any relation between students and sites ?

Comment: there's no relationship, I'm just about to try UNION operator, & it did not work

Comment: plz, Add your UNION code in the question for more help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Code; If you want just a list of data of both tables:

```
SELECT 
    SITE_ID AS S, LOCATION AS L, '' As SL, 0 As C, 'Site' As UType
FROM 
    SITES
WHERE 
    LOCATION LIKE 'Europe%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    STUDENT_ID As S, STUDENT_FNAME As L, STUDENT_LNAME AS SL, COUNTRY AS C, 'Student' As UType
FROM 
    STUDENTS
WHERE 
    COUNTRY NOT LIKE 'UK';
```

Comment: so I've changed 0 As C to ' ' As C, as it required the same datatype, then it seems to works. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't give a correct answer to the question. Also, why would you union these together? They are from different domains.

Comment: As following comments of question.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you want the `MINUS` operator.